# Non-latin characters in output

Tags: php, codeception

I am really new in using codeception and I have just created my first acceptance test according to guide. 
You can see that if I use a non-latin letter, the test won't pass. But I have on the page string "dneska láska". Moreover, you can see that the output has the letter "á" in console in some weard way changed.

```
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('perform actions and see result');
$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->see("dneska l", "h1");
$I->see("dneska", "h1");
$I->see("dneska láska", "h1");
```

You can see the output here:

```
There was 1 failure:

---------
1) Failed to perform actions and see result in WelcomeCept (tests\acceptance\WelcomeCept.php)

 Step  I see null,"h1"
 Fail  Failed asserting that any element by 'h1' on page /
 + <h1>dneska l├íska</h1>
 contains text 'dneska lßska'

 Scenario Steps:

 4. $I->see(null,"h1") at tests\acceptance\WelcomeCept.php:7
 3. $I->see("dneska","h1") at tests\acceptance\WelcomeCept.php:6
 2. $I->see("dneska l","h1") at tests\acceptance\WelcomeCept.php:5
 1. $I->amOnPage("/") at tests\acceptance\WelcomeCept.php:4


 FAILURES!
 Tests: 1, Assertions: 3, Failures: 1.
```

Comment: How is your site encoded, what encoding is your PHP test file in?

Comment: Oh, really. You are right. I checked it but I overlooked it obviously.